# Kendo grid update with form data in MVC application

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a kendo grid in an schtml page.  There are also text boxes and dropdown combo boxes on the page.  In addition, some of the grid cells are editable and other cells are computed based on the data entered by the user.

I need to return the grid data as well as the other text boxes and dropdown combo box values to the controller.

I have a button on the screen which will execute a javascript function when clicked.  In the function, I build an object which contains the data from the text boxes and dropdown combo box values.  This object is sent to the controller via ajax.

This is the basic code for the grid:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<TaxCertApp.ViewModels.SettlementMemoViewModel>()
    .Name("SettlementMemodGrid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(nr => nr.TaxYear).Width(50).Title("Tax Year");
        columns.Bound(nr => nr.OriginalAssessment).Width(100).Title("ORIG. ASSESSMENT").Format("{0:##########0}");
        columns.Bound(nr => nr.Reduction).Width(100).Title("REDUCTION").EditorTemplateName("Integer").EditorViewData(new { blurHandler = "computeFinalAssessment" });
        columns.Bound(nr => nr.FinalAssessment).Width(100).Title("FINAL ASSESSMENT").Format("{0:###,###,##0}");
        columns.Bound(nr => nr.Rate).Width(100).Title("RATE").EditorTemplateName("Currency");
        columns.Bound(nr=> nr.RefundSavings).Width(100).Title("REFUND/SAVINGS").Format("{0:###,###,##0}");
        columns.Bound(e => e.Type).Width(100).EditorTemplateName("TypeList").Title("TYPE (R S R/S)");
    })
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
    .Pageable()
    .Scrollable()
    .Events(e => e.Edit("OnEdit"))
    .Events(ev => ev.Change("OnChange"))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .Batch(true)
    .ServerOperation(false)
    .Model(model =>
    {
         model.Id(n => n.TaxYear);
         model.Field(n => n.OriginalAssessment).Editable(false);
         model.Field(n => n.Reduction).Editable(true);
         model.Field(n => n.FinalAssessment).Editable(false);
         model.Field(n => n.Rate).Editable(true);
         model.Field(n => n.RefundSavings).Editable(true);
         model.Field(n => n.Type).Editable(true);
     })
     .PageSize(20)
     .Read(read => { read.Action("FetchSettlementMemoGrid", "Forms").Data("BuildObjectGridSettMemo"); })
     )
 )
```

This is the basic code of the javascript function that executes on the button click:

```
function GenerateSettMemXLS() {

    var datepicker = $("#SettMemoDateSettled").data("kendoDatePicker");

    $('#SettMemoDateNSettledTitle').removeClass('required-field');

    if (!ValidateNegRecRequiredFields(datepicker)) {
        return false;
    }
    
    var combobox = $('#ddlFrmSettMemoCalendarNumber');
    var atty = $('ddlFrmSettMemoOurAttorney');

    var obj = {
        ReportType: 'XLS',
        FileNum: $('#txtFrmSettMemoFileNo').val(),
        Suffix: $('#ddlFrmSettMemoSuffix').val(),
        TaxCode: $('#txtFrmSettMemoTaxCode').val(),
        Class: $('#txtFrmSettMemoClass').val(),
        CalendarNumber: combobox.data('kendoComboBox').text(),
        DateSettled: datepicker.value(),
        AppraisalFee: $('#txtFrmSettMemoAppraisalFee').val(),
        FDTFee: $('#txtFrmSettMemoFDTFee').val(),
        ForwardingFee: $('#txtFrmSettMemoForwardingFee').val(),
        OurAttorney: atty.data('kendoComboBox').text(),
        RespondentAttorney: $('#txtFrmSettMemoRespondingAttorney').val(),
        Petitioner: $('#txtSettMemoPetitioner').val(),
        PropertyAddress: $('#txtSettMemoPropertyAddress').val(),
        SBL: $('#txtSettMemoSBL').val(),
        PropertyType: $('#txtSettMemoPropertyType').val(),
        SchoolDistrict: $('#txtSettMemoSchoolDistrict').val(),
    };


    $.ajax(
    {
        url: "/Forms/NegotiationRecordGenerateReport", // Controller/Action
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        datatype: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(obj),
        type: "POST",
        success: function (NegotiationRecFileName) {
            openNegotiationRecordReport(NegotiationRecFileName);
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Error retrieving file status "); alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
        }
    });

}
```

My question is how do I get the grid information into the object that I am sending to the controller.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated

Comment: Another way to do this would be to wire up the grid with the Update/Edit/Delete/Add cruds on the controller, or in your case batch update, and then wire a javascript event when the grid data is saved. If you have a paged grid with 1000 plus pages, how big will that payload be? That being said you can get the data using var gridData = $("#grid").data().kendoGrid.dataSource.data();

Comment: @RossBush - I was thinking about this.  If I add the Update to send the grid data to the controller, I would be able to save the grid data to the database and then the return would be to the view.  Upon returning to the view, how would I get the javascript function to execute?  If I can get the javascript function to execute, then the remaining form data would be collected into the object and passed to the controller via an ajax call.  How would I do that?

Comment: Here is a pretty good example. https://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-pass-additional-data-to-create-update-destroy-action-method